# gmaps.js returning old value for getRoutes

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, maps, gmaps.js

If there are multiple legs, the distance reported for each leg is the same.  Any idea why?  It reports the distance between the first two legs right, but then the distance between every other leg is the same as the first leg.  Probably just over-caffeinated at this point, but I can't see why.

Here is the code:

```
function marker(map, lat, lng, title, name) {
map.addMarker({
    lat: lat,
    lng: lng,
    title: title,
    click: function (e) {

        legs.push({destination: name, latitude: lat, longitude: lng, distance: null, time: null});

        var next_stop;

        if (legs.length > 1)
        {
            $.each(legs, function (index, value)
            {
                // Mileage In Between
               if (legs[(index + 1)])
               {
                   next_stop = legs[(index + 1)];

                map.getRoutes(
                    {
                        origin: [value.latitude, value.longitude],
                        destination: [next_stop.latitude, next_stop.longitude],
                        callback: function (e)
                        {
                            var time = 0;
                            var distance = 0;
                            for (var i=0; i<e[0].legs.length; i++)
                            {
                                time += e[0].legs[i].duration.value;
                                distance += e[0].legs[i].distance.value;
                            }

                            var miles = distance/1609.34;

                            var kilometers = distance/1000;

                            var timer = time/60;

                            legs[(index + 1)].distance = miles.toFixed(2);

                            alert(timer.toFixed(2) + " and " + miles.toFixed(2));
                        }
                    }
                );
            }

            }
            );
        }

        console.log(legs);

        a.$set('stops', legs);

    }
});
}
```

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the issue.

Comment: shouldn't the var distance and the miles calculation be moved out of the map callback to the beginning of the function ? The callback will only return one distance each time, but you want to sum over all legs ?

Comment: Yes, the mileage calculations will be moved out later.  Yes, I want a distance each time (leg), not a sum.

Comment: I noticed that if I start a new map instance each time, I get a different number..  Kind of wonky though..

Comment: well could be that the value of lat and lng aren't being updated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry for wasting your time everyone.  Apparently this is a known, unfixed bug with gmap.js:

https://github.com/hpneo/gmaps/issues/373

The fix is to find this code in gmaps.js:

```
    if (options.callback) {
    options.callback(self.routes, result, status);
  }
```

And replace it with:

```
    if (options.callback) {
    options.callback(result.routes, result, status);
  }
```